# Linq - Performant selection of specific class properties in list

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I'm having a class with several material properties (e.g . temperature). The cross section of a sample is represented by a list of class elements.
I only need material properties in multiple methods at specific positions of the cross section or indices, respectively.

At the moment I'm using a Linq-select to first create an IEnumerable of the needed property.
Than I'm creating a list using the IEnumerable, where I can select the wanted elements by index.
Example (indices is a List with :

```
var indices = new List<int>() {1, 3, 7, 15, 30, 50};
var Ts = microstructures.Select(x => x.T).ToList();

var list = new List<double>();
for (int i = 0; i < indices.Count; i++)
{
   list.Add(Ts[indices[i]]);
}
```

Is there a more efficient way without creating a list to perform this task?
microstructures has < 100 elements, indices ~ 10 and the properties of the microstructure can be complex classes themselves.

Comment: For < 100 elements, is performance really relevant?Have you measured how long time it takes? When discussing performance we should ignore the small inefficiencies and focus on improving the parts that actually take time.

Comment: You could use 2 foreach loop to avoid Ts allocation.

Comment: Performance is only relevant because I'm doing this billions of times during simulations. Before I try to change the layout of the legacy code. I want to try some tweaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may filter the T directly using the where overload that expose the object and it's index. [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-where-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-int32-system-boolean))))
Then replace the Select by a Select many to flattern List<List> to List

```
public class Toto { 
   public List<int> T { get; set; }
}
var target = new HashSet<int>{ 1, 3, 7, 15, 30, 50 };
var inputs = Enumerable.Range(0, 10) // generate Data Sample
                        .Select(x=>new Toto
                        {
                           T = Enumerable.Range(100*x,100).ToList()
                        });

var r = inputs.SelectMany(x => x.T.Where((y,i)=> target.Contains(i)));
```

[live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/opQeqM)